# c# Asp.net Validation Methods for textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, input

I'm new to using c# in asp.net

I was just wondering what the best methods of validation are for when it comes to checking a textbox that has to be number's (and 1 decimal point) only, I've read about ajax but I understand that this only works if the client supports it, so I'm now looking into new methods.

Also do these validation methods have the ability to prevent a event such as a button press from triggering and causing the web application to break?

Comment: Always validate data at client side as well as server side *(in code behind)*.

Comment: @Habib if client side validated, why to validate again on serverside?

Comment: @Freelancer This is because to give 2 level of security.
Client validation is prone to get hacked, server validation saves you to open your database to hackers

Comment: @Freelancer The client side validation is only for the ease of the user, refreshless validation. However, this is not at **all** secure. Validation should *always* take place both at the client and server.

Comment: @Habib Because you can never trust the user. If he disables JavaScript, he can post data to the server which will not be validated. ALWAYS perform server-side validation. Client-side validation is just a nice extra for the user, but not necessary, whereas server-side is an absolute necessity

Comment: @Steve ,Nipun does it effects the speed and increases overhead for application?

Comment: @Freelancer, just posted an answer with details, the main point is, never rely on client side validation only, as the client may have disabled javascript on the browser.

Comment: @Freelancer Everything going at server level puts some overhead however this is recommended if you are having confidential data.
But playing with confidential data is more important and this overhead can be ignored.
It will be a nightmare if your database is exposed to hackers :(

Comment: @NipunAmbastha ohh, thanx , from 2mmorow, 2 level validation. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always validate data at client side as well as server side *(in code behind)*. For example you can use the asp.net provided validation control which will provide you with Client side validation, In server side validation *(in C#)* you can implement your own logic for data validation. For example in your case you can use `double.TryParse` to see if the string entered in the `TextBox` is a valid double number.

The reason to have Both types of validation is:

- Client may have disabled javascript on the browser.
- Client's browser doesn't support Javascript ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398447/what-web-browsers-do-not-support-javascript-and-how-to-identify-which-browser-i))